# Pandas .concat(x , axis = 1) not lining up dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to use df.concat() to combine 2 dataframes. The issue is that they arent lining up. I am using the axis = 1 argument as well.

```
result df = pd.conat([df1,df2),axis =1)
```

The result I get is

```
Df1 : 
     a    b    c   
0         3   4
1         6   7


df2: 

      a   b    c    d   e 
0     8             9   10
1     11           12   13

result df: 
      a   b    c    d   e 
0         3    4
1         5    6
2     8              9   10
3     11            12   13
```

what I want:

```
      a   b    c    d   e 
0     8   3    4    9   10
1     11  6    7   12   13
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that `pd.concat` is what you want. You effectively want to substitute cols b and c from `df1` into `df2`. You could try a `join`.

```
df2 = df2.drop(columns=['b','c'])
df = df1.join(df2)
```

Comment: I confirm this works with pandas 1.5.3. 
You can declare column order to get it as needed:
df = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)[['a','b','c','d','e']]

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to replicate your problem and arrive at the correct solution. My pandas version is 1.5.3

```
import pandas as pd
### Create the dataframes
d0 = {'b': [3,6] , 'c': [4,7]}
d1 = {'a': [8,11],'d':[9,12], 'e':[10,13]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d0)
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d1)
### Combine
df = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)[['a','b','c','d','e']]
```

Output:
[image: df1.head()]
[image: df2.head()]
[image: df.head()]